# SQL Server : create dynamically queries to select all related data in DB based on entry table and ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion

I'm tasked to create a SQL statement which will create (and run?) multiple other queries which will select all related data outgoing from an given ID (uniqueidentifier) and a given table name.

It doesn't have to be that fast, but it should be able to use against every db, given only 1 ID and the table name.

In the DB, there are some 1:n, n:m etc. relations and not every table has a column named Id, some only have foreign-keys and it has to be fully dynamically and generic.

I tried to realise it by myself, but I'm not that good in SQL, I also tried some other scripts which will return the primary-foreign-key-relations but I'm stuck there so I'd thought you guys might help me :)

To be returned, I need (would be best) generated queries which I can run against the db and get all information returned (Are there other good return possibilities?)

Alternatively I could create this project in C#, but I'm stuck in attempt as well.

I'll appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: Sample data, table structures and desired output?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your schema look like? Do you actually know anything about SQL or LINQ?

Comment: I don't have sample data. Imagine any db structure.
I have multiple tables, which are related, some more, some less. Given is an ID for a specific column from a specific table. For this, I need to find all related data. And for the related data the related data and so on.
I think, the best output would be queries which I can run against the db.
I have tried some scripts which will return the primary-foreign key relations and tried upon this to do the task but I can't.

Comment: @ Sippy I've tried to generate a query that will join all the informations together wich was not working as excpected because of multidefinition of the tablename in the query wich I can't handle since the pc doesn't know wich instance of a table to use in wich line of the query when multiple occured
I also tried to generate a query for every  row per table etc but it wasn't working as expected (maybe because I'm not that good in sql)
I know the basics in SQl, MySQL, LINQ (select/insert/update and most joins but I'm clearly not an expert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will generate a a set of queries that can then be pasted pasted into ssms and executed.

You will need to specify the table, column and id value that you are interested in.

Also note that this will probably need tweaked to work with schemas etc. and you could execute the SQL returned with a cursor I am sure but this gets you on the right track I think:

```
DECLARE @idvalue int = 1
DECLARE @colName nvarchar(max) = 'myid'
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max) = 'Table_1'

DECLARE @tmp_Accounts TABLE (
PKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname
,PKTABLE_OWNER sysname
,PKTABLE_NAME sysname
,PKCOLUMN_NAME sysname
,FKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname
,FKTABLE_OWNER sysname
,FKTABLE_NAME sysname
,FKCOLUMN_NAME sysname
,KEY_SEQ smallint
,UPDATE_RULE smallint
,DELETE_RULE smallint
,FK_NAME nvarchar(max)
,PK_NAME nvarchar(max)
,deferrability smallint
)

insert into @tmp_Accounts exec sp_fkeys @tableName

select 
    'select * from ['+FKTABLE_NAME+'] where ['+FKCOLUMN_NAME+'] = '  
         + cast(@idvalue as nvarchar(max)) 
from 
    @tmp_Accounts 
where 
    PKCOLUMN_NAME = @colName
```

Also note you would need to tweak data types depending on the id selected.

E.G.

SQLFiddle - Getting queries to execute:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbf40/1

SQLFiddle - Executing returned queries:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbf40/2

Comment: Thanks! I tried it a bit and it looks good! I will implement this in C# and test it and then I will give feedback if it works properly :)

Comment: there is much you would need to add to make it robust - e.g. it would be better if it worked when the id column was not the same column used in the foreign key. also this will do nothing for many to many relationships etc. that are not directly referencing the specific table, for that you would need to do something quite a bit fancier that recursed through the linked tables.

Comment: @probird where is the feedback that you promised it 7 years ago?